# Handling region in a restful manner

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing a system that talks to multiple servers across different regions. Each of the regions for the same request will return unique results e.g. user a's device configuration might be different in ANZ to EMEA.

A few questions have come up about what is the best way to design the system so we get the most versatility.

Questions:

1. A function was created so if an API call is made without specifying a region, the results of all the regions will be returned. Is this a smart thing to do or would it be better to force a region to be specified?
2. What would be the best way to handle regions (ANZ, EMEA, INDIA, ASIA, AMER) in a restful manner. My first thoughts were /region/anz/userid/123, but if we want to do a global search for a user this would require making x amount of calls. Is this the better approach or would it be better to add the region at the end of the URL like so /userid/123?region=anz

Answer (score 0):

> My first thoughts were /region/anz/userid/123, but if we want to do a global search for a user this would require making x amount of calls.

The usual answer in REST would be to create a resource that provides a representation of the global search results.

```
GET /global/userid/123
```

Would be fine.

```
GET /global?userid=123
GET /userid/123/global
GET /userid/123?global
GET /userid/123?region=global
```

These are also all *fine*.  As far as a general purpose component is concerned, the URI is semantically opaque.  So you can use anything that makes the human beings happy.

When you have a cluster of related resources, it can be convenient to use identifiers that are easily described by a URI template.  See [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

On the web, the common uri template mechanism is that of an HTML form; and form processing rules call for sticking `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` values on the query string.  So an HTML friendly spelling might look more like

```
GET /report?userid=123&region=global
```

Of course, you can have "web form endpoints" that just redirect to the "real" target-uri, so it doesn't matter very much.